# How much thrust can a balloon generate with wings?

Tags: wing, thrust, glide-ratio, balloon

I have heard that some balloons have been made with wings, angled such that they generate some forward thrust during the ascent. Balloons can also theoretically generate thrust with wings during a descent.

This made me curious about how much thrust one might produce. I suspect the drag of the balloon will ensure it would not be a useful amount.

In general, I would think of a 10m diameter balloon, using hydrogen, or hot-air if your prefer. I think a common ascent rate is 5m/s, so if you could get as much as a 1:1 glide ratio, that'd be 5m/s of forward velocity.

Comment: This concept is used very successfully in [autonomous underwater gliders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_glider). As you say, the low density of air requires much larger volumes wich causes excessive drag. I am not aware of a successful application in air.

Comment: Variable buoyancy propulsion for UAV [is also researched](https://lynceans.org/all-posts/phoenix-makes-first-flight-with-variable-buoyancy-propulsion/).